# What is the fastest way to get the last elements of a list by ID with Datetime?

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime, timestamp

I have a huge `List<MyObject>`. `MyObject` had a property named *Timestamp* (`DateTime?`) and a *Code* (`string`).
I need to get the lasts Objects by timestamp for each code.

For example with this following input :

```
Code| A   | B   | Timestamp
A1  | ABC | DEF | Fri 7 Mar 2014 
B2  | ABC | GHI | Thu 6 Mar 2014 
A1  | DEF | GHI | Mon 10 Mar 2014 
B2  | DEF | GHI | Fri 7 Mar 2014 
C3  | GHI | JKL | Fri 7 Mar 2014
```

I need to get this :

```
Code| A   | B   | Timestamp
A1  | DEF | GHI | Mon 10 Mar 2014 
B2  | DEF | GHI | Fri 7 Mar 2014 
C3  | GHI | JKL | Fri 7 Mar 2014
```

In order to do this I did the following function :

```
private List<MyObject> GetLastsObjects(List<MyObject> input)
{
    var output = input.Where(x => x.Timestamp == x.Where(y => y.Code == y.Code)
                                                               .Max(tmp => tmp.Timestamp))
                      .ToList();
    return output;
}
```

It works but I have really bad performance with a huge input...

Do you know how can I optimized this function ? What is the fastest way to get the last elements by timestamp for each Code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to group the objects by code, reverse sort each group by timestamp and get the first result of each group:

```
var output = input
    .GroupBy(o => o.Code)
    .Select(g1 => g1.OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.Timestamp).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I understand the logic but your code returns a `List<DateTime?>` and not the `List<MyObject>` required :/

Comment: @Alex: Argh. I initially had a correct version (rolled back, you can see it again now) but then thought you only wanted the timestamps.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a [MaxBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) extension method. It will save you having to perform a complete sort only to select the top item, so will consequently have much more favourable memory characteristics and most likely be somewhat quicker. There's one in the [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) package.

So...

```
input.GroupBy(x => x.Code).Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.TimeStamp))
```